# Memory Leak when returning NSMutableDictionary object

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsmutabledictionary

I have memory leaks in the aTierOneData and when i tried [aTierOneData autorelease] , my app crashed.so how i can fix this memory leak.

Plese let me know

```
//===============================================================
  - ( NSMutableDictionary * ) getDataToDisplayTierOne:(NSString*)dbPath{
//================================================================
    NSMutableDictionary *aTierOneData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        const char *sql_query_stmt = "select * from main_categories";

        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {   NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

                NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                                   (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

                [aTierOneData setObject:aId forKey:aValue];

                [aValue release];
                [aId release];
            }
        }
    }   
    else{//Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to 
        sqlite3_close(database); 
    }

    return aTierOneData;

}


-(void)fetchDataForTierOne{
//===========================

    myTierOneDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    myTierOneDict = [myDBOperations getDataToDisplayTierOne:[appDelegate getDBPath]];
    NSArray *myTierOneDictKeys = [myTierOneDict allKeys];
    myTierOneData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)myTierOneDictKeys];

    if ([myTierOneData count] > 0 ){
        [self constructTierOnePicker];
    }
}
```

Comment: In the method that calls this method, what does it do with the returned dictionary?  Does it assign it to a retained iVar?  If so, then you should be able to do:  return [aTierOneData autorelease];

Comment: What you are doing exactly in the method from where you are calling ?

Answer (score 1):

You are leaking the `sqlite3` object, because you don't call `sqlite3_close` on it when `sqlite3_open` succeeds.

Your method is named `getDataToDisplayTierOne:`.  By [Cocoa convention](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), that method should return an object that the caller does *not* own.  So you should be sending `autorelease` to `aTierOneData` before returning it.  If you want the caller to own the returned object, you should name the method something like `newDataToDisplayTierOne:` or `mutableCopyDataToDisplayTierOne:`.

We can't help you understand why your app crashes unless you show us the code that calls `getDataToDisplayTierOne:` and uses the returned dictionary.

#### Update

In `fetchDataForTierOne`, you are allocating/initing an empty `NSMutableDictionary`, storing a pointer to it in `myTierOneDict`, and then immediately leaking it by setting `myTierOneDict` to the return value of `getDataToDisplayTierOne:`.  Why did you think you needed to store a pointer to an an empty dictionary in `myTierOneDict`?

The code you posted doesn't send `release` or `autorelease` to the dictionary created in `getDataToDisplayTierOne:`, so you might be leaking that dictionary also.

The code you posted doesn't send `release` or `autorelease` to the array that `myTierOneData` points to, so you might be leaking that also.

Comment: I am releasing this myTierOneDict and myTierOneData in the dealloc method

Answer (score 0):

do

```
return [aTierOneData autorelease];
```

as cocoa naming convention, [You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). Your function name doesn't imply that this function create an object that is owned by you, so `autorelease` the return value. If you need to hold the data that is returned, take ownership of it by sending `retain` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

In the function fetchDataForTierOne, first line  myTierOneDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; is creating memory leak. You are creating a dictionary and assigned a different dictionary returned by getDataToDisplayTierOne function.

So, the dictionary created in the first line of function fetchDataForTierOne will become unreferenced and will create a leak. No need to write first line.

Second, return the dictionary with autorelease and retain it in fetchDataForTierOne function. After completing the usage release it.

Updated Code:

//===============================================================

-( NSMutableDictionary * ) getDataToDisplayTierOne:(NSString*)dbPath{
//================================================================

```
NSMutableDictionary *aTierOneData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
{
    const char *sql_query_stmt = "select * from main_categories";

    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql_query_stmt, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {   NSString *aValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
            (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

            NSString *aId = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 0)];

            [aTierOneData setObject:aId forKey:aValue];

            [aValue release];
            [aId release];
        }
    }
}   
else{//Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to 
    sqlite3_close(database); 
}

return [aTierOneData autorelease];
```

}

-(void)fetchDataForTierOne{

//===========================

```
myTierOneDict = [[myDBOperations getDataToDisplayTierOne:[appDelegate getDBPath]]retain];
NSArray *myTierOneDictKeys = [myTierOneDict allKeys];
myTierOneData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:(NSArray*)myTierOneDictKeys];

if ([myTierOneData count] > 0 ){
    [self constructTierOnePicker];
}
```

[myTierOneDict release];
}

Comment: can i use the myTierOneDict varibale without intilaising?